Why this nginx dockerfile run for a minute and return unhealthy status and report bad getway
I am very new to the docker. This is my first individual Dockerfile. After running this Dockerfile my website continue shows 502 Bad Gateway. The status shows unhealthy after running for a minute.
FROM composer as builder
ARG PHP_FPM_VER=8.2

LABEL maintainer="tan <@gmail.com>"

WORKDIR /app

COPY conf/composer.json /app/

RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction


FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine


RUN apk add --no-cache nginx curl libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql \
    && apk add --no-cache supervisor curl


COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY conf/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

COPY --from=builder /app/vendor /var/www/vendor
COPY src /var/www/html

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=10s --start-period=10s --retries=3 \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1

EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /var/www/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I have tried add supervisord.conf, rewrite Health Check Command. They did not work.
